# Comparison between POSIX object and string in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I work with data frames containing POSIX variables in GMT.
I often need to subset them, and I find if very useful to be able to compare strings to POSIX objects (e.g. `date > "2015-12-01"`).

I was wondering if anyone could provide an explanation for the following behaviour in R.

```
date_str <- "2015-01-10"
date <- as.POSIXct(date_str, tz = "GMT")
date == date_str
```

`date_str` is coerced to a POSIX object, using `as.POSIXct(date_str, tz="")` so the result will be `FALSE` if *I am not in GMT*.

I realise it is easy to fix by explicit conversion, but I was wondering if their is **any reason why R uses the time zone of the system as opposed to the time zone of the POSIX object**, which I feel the user generally wants.

Comment: "which I feel the user generally wants" Others might feel differently. Relying on this automatic conversion is dangerous and lazy.

Comment: With regards to the  order of precedence (`?Comparison`) I'd say R compares `strftime(date) == date_str`, i.e. `"2015-01-10 01:00:00" ==  "2015-01-10"` (character representations), which is `FALSE`.

Comment: Relying on implicit conversion is bad enough. Asking that the implicit conversion behave differently depending on the attributes of the object being compared to is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: use your own `==` like `\`%==%\` <- function(x, y) x == if (inherits(x, 'POSIXct')) as.POSIXct(y, tz = attr(x, 'tzone')) else y; date %==% date_str` this returns true